# Read a file into Map<Integer, ArrayList<Double>>

Tags: java

I saw some similar questions, but mine is a little different.

I define a

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<Double>> fl;
```

My input .txt file:

1 0.56 0.57 0.73 ..

2 2.3 3.50 ...

9 4.98 0.99 ..

How to read the file into the map fl?

Thanks!

Comment: You want full code or simply an advice? As an advice for each line you cast the first value to an integer and then you create an ArrayList in which you add the subsequent values which have been cast to Double. Once you have done that you use map.put(key, value), where key is the integer and value is the ArrayList and then move on to the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a try.
I've compiled and run the code.

Make sure the input file is in the same directory as your project if you use an IDE.-- This only applies if you do not modify the path below.

```
package fileread;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class FileRead {

   private static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
   private static BufferedReader reader;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try
      {
          reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input"));
          //or reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\full-path-to-your-file));
          String line;
          while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
         {
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            Integer i;
            Double d;
            ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
            i = Integer.valueOf(tokens[0]);

            for(int j = 1; j < tokens.length; j++)
                list.add(Double.valueOf(tokens[j]));
            map.put(i, list);
        }
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        //break execution
    }finally
    {
        if(reader != null)
            try 
            {
                reader.close();
            }catch (IOException ex) {
                //don't break :)
            }
    }

    for(Integer i : map.keySet())
    {
        ArrayList<Double> l = map.get(i);
        System.out.print("Line " + i + ": ");
        for(Double d: l)
            System.out.print(d + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

   }    
 }
```

Comment: "or class file if you use the command line" -- this is incorrect, the working directory can be other than one containing class file.

Comment: For the above code. Of course it can be, but then you need to specify the full path in the FileReader. I didn't want to make it too easy so the author of the question can learn something about the Buffers.

Comment: Yeah. Well, file reading using the buffers is more or less a standard way of doing it.

Comment: @SlowTrout it's not what I meant. You can execute the existing code from different directory and working directory will be not the one, in which the class file is located.

Comment: Yeah I admit that's true, but again it's not the meaningful part of the answer. Talking about working directories right now will simply create more confusion. I will edit my answer.

Comment: It works. Another question, is there some data structure like pair ? For example, I want to map a flow id(int) to a pair of ip address (string, string). But I think Map<Integer, Map<String, String>> is not good. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Why not just make an object IPPair that encapsulates 2 strings and use that as a data type.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Scanner` and first call `Scanner.readInt()` that will give you the first integer.

Then call `Scanner.readLine()` that will give you all the remaining double in the line as a String. Split it and parse everything to double.

Repeat the same till end of file.

Answer (score 1):

The code for parsing the file and populating the map should be like below

```
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("c:/input .txt")));
                String line = "";
                Map<Integer, ArrayList<Double>> fl = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Double>>();

                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] strArray = line.split(" ");
                    for (int i=0;i<strArray.length;i++) {
                        ArrayList<Double> value = new ArrayList<Double>();
                        int key=0;
                        if(i==0){
                             key =Integer.valueOf(strArray[0]);
                        }
                        else{
                            value.add(Double.valueOf(strArray[i]));
                        }
                        fl.put(key, value);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```